# Azure Function deployment slow

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-functions

We're finding that a deployment of our Azure Function (AFRv1 / Node.JS) is taking a really long time (15-25 minutes). The cause of this is clearly the number of files in node_modules, but I feel like there must be a better way around this that I haven't looked at.

We deploy the application and node_modules (pre-yarn-installed) as a zip package using the `Azure App Service Deploy` VSTS task.

Is there an optimised way of deployment using an archive that doesn't take such a long time? Perhaps something that is better at differential deployments?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can do two things to reduce deployment time (and cold start time too):

1. Bundle your node modules with WebPack, have a look at [Azure Functions Pack tool](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-pack).

and/or

2. Use [Run from Package](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/84) deployment.

Comment: I'm an idiot for not thinking of webpack (since we use in the browser), but great to know about `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_ZIP`! Thanks :)

Comment: Is Run-From-Package still preview? Supported in production?

Comment: @RichardSzalay I haven't seen it GA, so my guess is it's in preview. I believe the latest Visual Studio uses it for Function App deployment, so it's pretty stable, but might be a concern for support indeed.

Comment: Run-From-Package is now GA: https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/84